# result of input box times 2 appears in window not div

Tags: javascript, html, button, input, parsefloat

I'm trying to get a text box where you can enter a number and then you click the button and it will multiply it by two and display that result in theDiv. Right now, it opens a new page for the result, and displays the entered number, not the number times two. What am I doing wrong? Beginner here, please be gentle! Thank you!!

```
<html>
<script>
function doubleit()
{
var theNumber=document.write(parseFloat(document.getElementById('theInput').value));
var doubleNumber =document.getElementById('theNumber')*2;
document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML(document.getElementById('doubleNumber'))
}
</script>
<body>
<p>Value: <input type="text" id="theInput" value="" size=10>
<input type="button" id="theButton" value="click me!" onclick="doubleit()"></p>
<div id="theDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the call to `document.write` that is replacing the page. Remove it:

```
var theNumber=parseFloat(document.getElementById('theInput').value);
```

When you want the value of a variable, you shouldn't use `document.getElementById`:

```
var doubleNumber = theNumber * 2;
```

`innerHTML` is a property, not a method:

```
document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = doubleNumber;
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try This Solution :**

Use the id of your button to call the function to calculate result.

```
theButton.onclick = function doubleit()
{
    //Simply get the number from user and parse it as float.
    var theNumber=parseFloat(document.getElementById('theInput').value);
    //Multiply it with 2
    var doubleNumber =theNumber*2;

    //Display the result in another div
    document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = doubleNumber;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/bNV9A/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var doubleNumber = Number(theNumber, 10)*2;
document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML(doubleNumber);
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
function doubleit()
{
var theNumber=parseFloat(document.getElementById('theInput').value) * 2;
document.getElementById('theDiv').innerHTML = theNumber;
}
```